# Перестаньте бездумно удалять метку C++ у вопросов C++/CLI

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Я постоянно вижу, как удаляют метку C++ у вопросов, где используется C++/CLI.
Дело в том, что в таких вопросах очень часто используются **оба** языка: и C++, и C++/CLI. Поэтому метка C++ там должна быть!
И неважно, что чаще всего это ошибка задавшего вопрос и код может быть переписан полностью на одном языке. Язык в вопросе есть - метка должна быть!

Конечно, если вопрос **только** по C++/CLI, то метка C++ не нужна и её можно удалить.

Что с этим можно сделать? Как донести информацию до всех рьяных плюсистов?

Comment: А примеры будут?

Comment: @Qwertiy видимо, по следам [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1351337/176217). Об остальных случаях не знаю, но, наверное, будет достаточно по метке пройтись поиском.

Comment: Да, достаточно пройтись по метке поиском.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, по метке поиском должен пройтись тот, кого что-то не устраивает, и предоставить примеры.

Comment: Не понял. Кажется, что в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1351337/215103) используется только C++/CLI, а не оба языка. Но метку вы все равно поставили. Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала давайте определимся, а что же такое вообще C++/CLI. Этот язык стандартизован ECMA и имеет [такое определение](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-372/):

> C++/CLI is an extension of the C++ programming language as described in ISO/IEC 14882:2003, Programming languages — C++. In addition to the facilities provided by C++, C++/CLI provides additional keywords, classes, exceptions, namespaces, and library facilities, as well as garbage collection.

Т.е. это **расширение** языка C++ стандарта 2003 года. Очевидно, расширение подразумевает надмножество, т.е. помимо возможностей C++ имеются и дополнительные: новые ключевые слова, классы, исключения и т.д.

Это как C++ заимствовал в своё время многое из C и, конечно, ещё можно написать программу, которая будет компилироваться как C, так и C++ компиляторами одновременно. С эквивалентностью поведения такой программы дело обстоит уже несколько сложнее.

Если у нас есть исходный код, который может быть скомпилирован **только как** C++/CLI, однозначно неуместно иметь на вопросе с таким кодом метки C++. Совершенно не важно сколько бы там раз не использовались унаследованные возможности от C++03.

Совмещать метки C++ и C++/CLI уместно только тогда, когда либо нужно создать идентичный исходный код, способный переварить как C++ так и C++/CLI отдельно (вряд ли это вообще кому-то нужно), либо речь о взаимодействии программных сущностей, одна из которых написана на C++ (который уже не переваривается как C++/CLI), другая на C++/CLI - например, взаимодействие двух библиотек, собранных разными компиляторами.

Обычно невозможно совместить в одном исходном коде разные языки программирования, хотя здесь сразу приходят на ум какие-нибудь ассемблерные вставки в C или C++. В таком случае вполне допустимо комбинировать метки. А вешать метку C++ только лишь потому, что C++/CLI код содержит неявное упоминание `std::` - спасибо, не надо.

N.B. Почему автор (или не только автор) может хотеть довесить метку [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) на свой вопрос по C++/CLI? Да хотя бы потому, что C++ более популярен и авось, кто-то из "рьяных плюсистов" всё же сможет дать ответ (или хотя бы наводящий комментарий) для решения проблемы ТС, которая по сути может и не касаться не только C++/CLI, но и C++, а проистекать из нарушения каких-то базовых принципов программирования (на любом языке).

Comment: У Visual C++ есть и другие расширения: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/keywords-cpp?view=msvc-170#microsoft-specific-c-keywords Что заставляет именно для C++/CLI выжигать метку С++, наличие отдельного стандарта? Насчет популярности - тут видимо лучше рекомендовать довешивать метку [.net], если хотят, чтобы вопрос увидело больше народу.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight у практически любого компилятора есть расширения, но есть и основная стезя. Основная стезя в случае с c++/cli именно c++/cli, а не c++. Если MS вдруг перестанет поддерживать новые стандарты плюсов, то вангую, что на новых вопросах метка [tag:c++] начнёт утрачивать свой смысл и будет появляться какой-нибудь [tag:ms-c++]. Если бы в c++/cli регулярно обновлялась версия c++, т.е. c++/cli было бы расширением над последним c++, поддерживаемым VS, то ситуация была бы, конечно, другой. PS. [.net] в 4-6 раз (смотря по каким критериям считать) менее популярная метка, чем [c++] на ruSO,

Comment: Стандарт не обновляется, но реализация то поддерживает новые возможности. То есть в C++/CLI можно писать `if constexpr (sizeof(int*) == 4) Console::WriteLine("32 bit");`, это компилируется в VS2017 при включенном С++17.

Comment: Частично согласен, но не совсем. Любая библиотека расширяет возможности языка. Значит, указав метку `boost`, нужно не ставить метку `c++`? Или указав метку `pandas`, нужно не ставить метку `python`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Буст - это библиотека для языка C++. А C++/CLI - не библиотека, а другой язык. Я думаю в этом разница.